# What is the difference between "soldato" and "militisto"?

Tags: word-difference, meaning

I have recently started studying Esperanto on Duolingo.

In an exercise about professions, it used "soldato" to mean "soldier" and "milito" to mean "war", but, given this, couldn't you just add the "-ist" suffix to get the word "militisto" for soldier?

Is it wrong or is there a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laŭ la difinoj en PIV, [soldato](https://vortaro.net/#soldato_kdu) estas *ordinara ano de armeo* kaj [militisto](https://vortaro.net/#militisto_kdu) estas *profesia armeano*.

Militisto estas profesiulo, sed soldato ne nepre estas tia. Tial rekrutigo tuj rezultas soldatojn, sed ne militistojn.

Soldato estas cetere la plej malaltranga ano de armeo kaj kiam oni uzas tiun vorton oni iel substrekas tion.

Indas noti ke [oficiro](https://vortaro.net/#oficiro_kdu) estas militisto, sed ne soldato.

Comment: Hm, kiel vi nomas oficirojn en pactempa rezervo? Ili kiuj havas normalan laboron, sed ĉe militotempo rolas kiel oficiroj. Ĉu ili estas militistoj aŭ soldatoj?

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas, dum pacaj tempoj ili estas `rezervistoj`. Se vi volas priskribi ilian rolon dum milita tempo, vi devas konsideri ilian rangon kaj la profesiecon de ilia rolo en tiu momento. Se ili estos oficiroj, do ili tiam estos militistoj, aŭ armeanoj, sed ne soldatoj. Kiel ĉiam, tio dependas de la persono kiun vi celas informi. `soldato` estas ĝenerala kaj komprenebla. Invadatoj ekzemple ne nepre scias pri rangoj, ili vidas nur soldatojn.

Comment: Pri "Indas noti ke oficiro estas militisto, sed ne soldato.": Ĉu tio eble dependas de la lando? En la svisa armeo estas ankaŭ ne-profesiaj oficiroj. (Vidu [Grade der Schweizer Armee](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grade_der_Schweizer_Armee))